# I am trying to pass data between modules in a node.js project, but I'm missing something

Tags: node.js

OK! Something is escaping me.

My capstone project is designed to add value to the BnB we run out of our home. We want to put a tool in the hands of our guests that will give them a means of looking at the weather in our area, both now and for the next week so they can plan what to wear when they go adventuring around the area. We want them to be able to look up restaurants in the local area and find reviews that will help them decide where to go for meals (we are a BnB we don't feed them). And, finally, we want them to be able to look up all the local 'places to go' and 'things to see'.

All of this functionality is based on geolocation, requiring our address as a base and our location coordinates.

I am trying to build a module that will return three things:

```
geocode.loc (which is the human readable geocode location)
geocode.lat (which is the latitude associated with the location)
geocode.lng (which is the longitude associated with the location)
```

These data points will be passed throughout  my app to the other apis I am using:

```
a 'weather' api to return local weather
a 'restaurants' api to return local restaurants
an 'attractions' api to return local attractions
```

Below is the code in question:

```
'use strict';
//  this module connects to the Google geocode api and returns the formatted address and latitude/longitude for an address passed to it

const request = require('request'),
    req_prom  = require('request-promise');

const config  = require('../data/config.json');

const geocode_loc = 'Seattle, WA';
const geocode_key = config.GEOCODE_KEY;

const options = {
    url: `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${geocode_loc}&key=${geocode_key}`,
    json: true
};

let body = {};

let geocode = request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
        body = {
            loc: body.results[0].formatted_address,
            lat: body.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
            lng: body.results[0].geometry.location.lng
        };
        return body;
    }
});


module.exports.geocode = geocode;
```

Comment: You should consider posting the code in the actual post. You question isn't useful to future users if the gist link goes away. And many won't click through on the link.

Comment: I've been criticized for not using gists in the past. It's hard to know which way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing code that's asynchronous. By the time you are exporting `geocode`, the value is not set yet.

Instead of exporting the `geocode` value, you should export a function. The function should take callbacks (just like `request`) or use Promises, or use async/await.

This is how I would write this:

```
let geocode = () => {
  return new Promise((rej, res) => {
    request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
      const body = {
        loc: body.results[0].formatted_address,
        lat: body.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
        lng: body.results[0].geometry.location.lng
      };
      res(body);
    }
  }
});
```

Then from your other modules you can call the geocode function and use `then()` to do something when the request completes.

Comment: Evert: thank you for the confirmation, it is almost identical with what I finally came up with. The main difference is I used request-promise rather than a native Promise instance. I verified the exporting module to be working fine. However, on the import side I get nothing returned from the geocode call. No errors. Nothing. I am newbie enough to realize I have done something wrong on the import side. Can you show me an example of the import side to confirm?

Comment: @doug5solas it looks like you are not actually using `req_prom` in your latest version. Can you try to rewrite it to use it instead, and show me an example of what you tried on the import side? Once you've done that, I'll update my answer to correct it.

Comment: Evert I am embarrassed to say that I solved the problem with req_prom and didn't know it because I made the rookie mistake of not firing the browser of so I couldn't see the results of my console.log statement in my route. Thank you for the help.